# Best Android app for blocking malicious/spam calls

Tags: android, spam

I get about 5 or 6 robocalls a day from malicious sources trying to scam me or steal my identity. I have used apps in the past to identify bad calls, but they haven't seemed very effective. What is the best app for Android to help me screen out these bad phone calls?

Comment: Can you update your question with how you define "best"?  YouMail is very popular, but whether or not it is the "best" would be dependent on your definition of "best".

Answer (score 1):

was just chatting with a friend on this topic, found this question while researching. dropping my notes below since no answers. hopefully this will trigger more input. :)

Android did have a system where incoming spammers were identified as possible spam callers (if I recall correctly, the number calling in was highlighted in red with a note) I'm on an iphone now, was expecting a similar service from apple.
has been a while since I've checked, there were a few apps providing a mutually maintained/shared spam list.

looking at a few forums discussions

- seems some us telcos offer spam call detection/blocking as a service, I havne't found this in Au yet. looks like a viable service to pitch.
- best forums discussions I found nominated use of do not disturb with exceptions for callers on your contact list. My voicemail tells callers to text instead of calling and I regularly tell business/social acquaintances to text before calling unless it's a scheduled meeting.
  these apps were reccomended in forums, I haven't used them.
  shouldianswer
  RoboKiller
  Hiya